# The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await, conceptual

I'm confused. How can one or many `Task` run in parallel on a single thread? My understanding of *parallelism* is obviously wrong.

Bits of MSDN I can't wrap my head around:

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be
>   created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async
>   method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current
>   synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the
>   method is active.

.. and:

> Between starting a task and awaiting it, you can start other tasks.
>   The additional tasks implicitly run in parallel, but no additional
>   threads are created.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They don't run in parallel, they take turns.  When progress is blocked for the running Task, it stores its state and yields control to a ready Task.  It's cooperative multitasking, not true parallelism.

Threads operate on the sample principle.  However there are several key differences I'd like to highlight.

First, simply because `async`/`await` aren't OS threads:

- Tasks won't see different Thread IDs
- Thread-local storage is not automatically context-switched when a Task yields.

Secondly, differences in behavior:

- `async`/`await` use cooperative multitasking, Win32 threads use pre-emption.  So it's necessary that all blocking operations explicitly yield control using the `async`/`await` model.  So you can end up blocking an entire thread and all its Tasks by making a blocking call to a function not written to yield.
- Tasks won't be executed in parallel on a multiprocessing system.  Since re-entrancy is controlled, this makes keeping data structures consistent a whole lot easier.

As Stephen points out in a comment, you *can* get simultaneous execution in multiple OS threads (along with all the complexity and potential race conditions) if you use a multithreaded synchronization context.  But the MSDN quotes were about the single-threaded context case.

Finally, other places this same design paradigm is used, you can learn a lot about good practices for `async`/`await` by studying these:

- Win32 *Fibers* (uses the same call style as threads, but cooperative)
- Win32 *Overlapped I/O* operations, Linux *aio*
- *Coroutines*

Comment: "blocked" might be a confusing term to use here, since the goal of async is to avoid blocking.

Comment: +1. Note that the `async` method saves its state and yields when it is blocked *on an `await`*. If it's running blocking code (like `Thread.Sleep`), then it won't save its state and yield.

Comment: @Cory: Individual Tasks get blocked, the thread doesn't (as Stephen says, this is true only if you use coroutines for everything).

Comment: I think that it should be made clear, why MS WROTE this. Many people think, that "async" makes a method run asynchronously (on a separate thread). No it doesnt. And also `await SomeMethodAsync()` doesn't create a new thread, just because of AWAIT. A new thread is created if SomeMethodAsync creates a new thread (which it does not necessarily do)

Comment: Yes, not arguing about correctness, just suggesting to reduce ambiguity on what you mean by "block" (as Stephen did, +1).

Comment: @BenVoigt: A lot of your updated answer is only true for `async` methods executed within a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext` (such as a UI context). If they are run in a console app or from a background thread, then `Task`s will execute on the thread pool and *will* execute in parallel (on multiple threads) unless you `await` each one individually.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks Ben, I will look into "cooperative multitasking" and "coroutines". It'll take me some time to dive into those concepts. I'll be *right* back.

Comment: @Stephen: Updated somewhat.  These MSDN quotes would be just plain wrong with a context linked to the thread pool, wouldn't they?