# If an async method is single threaded how can it be run in the background?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to understand async/await and have read a number of articles but am still confused about the synchronous/asynchronous nature.

I have the following test console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = FooAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("After FooAsync");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("After that");

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static async Task FooAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before delay");
    await Task.Delay(1);
    Console.WriteLine("After delay");
}
```

The code gives output along the lines of:

```
Before delay
After FooAsync
After that
After that
After that
After that
After delay
After that
.
.
```

I understand that async/await will *not* create a separate thread for processing and that at the point `FooAsync` reaches the `await Task.Delay(1)` line it will return back to `Main` as the task will not yet have completed, however, as we are only running on a single thread can someone explain what triggers the `FooAsync` method to resume at some arbitrary point within `Main` before `Main` can then continue?

**Update**
I take it back and i3arnon and dariogriffo are correct. The code does use multiple threads (as I'd have seen before had looked in the debugger or done the obvious as kha suggested). I'd been confused by the Threads section on the following page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_Threads not realising that a "continuation" actually refers to a continuation task schedule to run as soon as the task being "awaited" finishes.

Comment: Answer by i3arnon is correct but if you want to understand it fully, replace your FooAsync with this:         `private static async Task FooAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before delay on " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            await Task.Delay(1);
            Console.WriteLine("After delay on " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }` and see that before and after are done on separate threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This isn't single threaded**.

When the delay task completes the rest of the method is posted to the `ThreadPool` and runs concurrently with your main thread. The "trigger" here is the callback of the internal `System.Threading.Timer` being used inside `Task.Delay`.

This behaviour depends on the `SynchronizationContext`. In a UI environment this would have been posted to the same UI thread and would have to wait until that thread is free.

If you would have been waiting for the task returned from `FooAsync` *then* you would only have a single thread **running** each time.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9212343/1497596) for how to wait for the task returned by `FooAsync` within `Main` so that the continuation for `FooAsync` runs on the main thread. Also, note that without waiting for `FooAsync`, an exception thrown by `FooAsync` will be silently swallowed.

Answer (score 2):

Async/await may create new threads OR NOT, it depends of the nature of the operation.
If the operation is an IO (for example disks/network operations) probably is coded in a way it will not spin a new thread. You can read from here:

[The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993750/the-async-and-await-keywords-dont-cause-additional-threads-to-be-created)

If you create your own Async operation and you create a thread, that's a different story, that's why you shouldn't do async over sync

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx

You can check this also but using Thread.CurrentThread to get the Id of the process. (Add that to a Console.WriteLine)

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty common misconception that the `async` or `await` keywords create new threads. They don't.

The threads are created by running a `Task`. In this case, the thread is created by the `Task.Delay` call.